# Unique ID for login in iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, keychain, uniqueidentifier

I want to generate a unique ID for every user when the user uses the app for the first time. The login happens in the backend and user need not enter mail id or mobile number etc. So what is the best way to ensure that an unique ID is generated for every user? Also if user uninstalls and installs the app again that particular user should not be treated as a new user. How do I handle this situation? Please help...

Thanks

Comment: Save Device UDID for new user. That will never change :)

Comment: @JP_Mob And how do you think you are going to get the device's UDID?

Answer (score 3):

You should use UUID (not UDID). because as per apple guide line UDID can not use in coding. it will rejected by apple

But If use UUID than it will change after app will reinstall again. to solve this you have to save this UUID in keychain first time and have load from keychain every time you get

for this [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/SSKeychain) you can use.

You can make you unique key as well instead of UUID. that may be combination of your user detail like email and mobile num.

Comment: @Akshara Please accept the answer if you go with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
  NSUUID *myUUID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
                NSLog(@"uuid is %@",[myUUID UUIDString]);
                NSString *deviceId = [myUUID UUIDString];
```

This will be unique.

Comment: Yes this is unique but it will change if app is uninstall and again install. So you need to store in keychain